# For loop through tuple A and increace tuple Ai given size N to Ni of iterable

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop, tuples

I´m trying to iterate trough elements where list N return an iterator, which goes through all possible tuples A, where Ai changes from 0 to Ni. the elements are always and int. A solution or a path to a solution with for loops and while loops is preferred.

```
def f(*args):
    lst = []
    for i in range(args[0]):
        for x in range(args[1]):
            for a in range(args[2]):
                for v in range(args[3]):
                    lst.append((i,x,a,v))
    return lst

print(f(5, 3, 1, 5))
```

This code works, but I don't want it hard coded: let's say if I want to input another int, lets say: `print(f(5, 3, 1, 5, 6))` <- it should work for that as well.

So the question is how to make a loop like the one above without the hard coding?

I have tried to use a `while` loop and a `for` loop inside the `while`:

```
   def f(*args):
    cnt = 0
    lst = []
    while len(args) > cnt:
        print(cnt)
        for i in range(args[cnt]):
            lst.append(i)
            print(lst)
        cnt += 1
    return lst
        
print(f(5, 3, 1, 5))
```

this is the correct output of the first code snippet and this is what I want without the hard coding:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you could do it is:

```
def f(*args):
    res = [[]]
    for z in map(range, args):
        res = [tuple(x)+(y,) for x in res for y in z]
    return res
f(5,3,1,5)
```

Comment: you opened my eyes for a new way to think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion for this. It replaces the unknown number of layered `for` loops.

```
def fr(tt, idx = 0):
   lst = []
   if idx == len(tt)-1:  # last index, just loop
      for x in range(tt[idx]):
         lst.append(tt[:-1] + (x,))
      return lst
   for x in range(tt[idx]): # loop and call child loops
      l2 = tt[:idx] + (x,) + tt[idx+1:] # update this index
      lst.extend(fr(tuple(l2), idx+1)) # iterate next level
   return lst

print(fr((5, 3, 1, 5)))
print(fr((5, 3, 1, 5, 6)))
```

Output

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 0, 4), ......., (4, 2, 0, 3), (4, 2, 0, 4)]
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0, 0, 3), ......., (4, 2, 0, 4, 4), (4, 2, 0, 4, 5)]
```

Comment: Works like a charm and well explained!